# Изменение размера балуна, заданного через json (API Яндекс.Карт)

Tags: javascript, json, yandex-maps-api

Размер балуна нужно задавать в зависимости от разрешения экрана, иначе на мобильных балун не влезает в видимую область. Задача осложняется тем, что меток много и их параметры, в том числе балун, задаются через json. Подскажите, какие есть варианты это сделать? Как менять размеры балуна в зависимости от разрешения экрана?

Comment: А как именно вы сейчас задаёте размеры балунов, что они не влезают в экран? Приводите пример кода в любой песочнице. В норме они должны становиться панелью для очень узких экранов. Но также вам ничего не должно мешать задавать параметры всем балунам разом через родительские объекты примерно так: myMap.options.set('balloonContentLayoutWidth', 300);